# Magento downloader upgrade conflict 1.9.2.0 > 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, upgrade, package, conflict

I'm trying to update Magento from version 1.9.2.0 to 1.9.2.2.
Unfortunately, there is a conflict error during installation/updating.

For example when I try to upgrade a package I get the following error:

```
Checking dependencies of packages
Already installed: community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.3, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Magento 1.9.2.2, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Credis 1.9.2.2, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.2.2, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.2.2, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.2.2, skipping

CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.2.2 conflicts     with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.0
Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2 conflicts with:     community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.2.0,     community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.2.0, community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.2.0, community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.0, community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.2.0, community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.2.0, community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.2.0, community/Magento_Mobile 1.9.2.0, community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.2.0
Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.2 conflicts with:     community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.0
Package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.0
Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.0
Package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.0
Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.0
Package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.0
Package community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.2 conflicts with: community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.0
Package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.0, community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.2.0
Package community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.2 conflicts with: community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.0

Checking dependencies of packages
Already installed: community/Lib_Credis 1.9.2.2, skipping

CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.0

Checking dependencies of packages

CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.0
Package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.0, community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.2.0
```

Some comments (for testing purpose)

- Removed the .htaccess file(s)
- Removed magento_all_latest.txt
- Removed pkginfo
- Deleted all caches
- Disabled all caches
- Changed the permissions

Comment: Can you FTP the files directly to your server?

Comment: I have access to all files/folders etc. Which files do I need to update/replace?

Comment: You can upload all your files via FTP (Test first!) This will ensure all the correct files have replaced your old ones

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Mage_All_Latest.txt file from this location in root Magento folder - /pkginfo/Mage_All_Latest.txt and then re-run the install of extensions from downloader.